# Reach other sublibraries with reflection (C#)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, system.reflection

I have a Visual Studio solution with three C# projects that each compiles into three different DLLs. Let's call the main one `Logic`. The other two are optional, and can be included in other applications or not, but the main DLL has to be included. Let's call the other two `Logic.Editor` and `Logic.OptionalLogic`. They both depend on the main DLL `Logic`.

This is the architecture I want, because generally the `Logic.Editor` and `Logic.OptionalLogic` don't communicate. I have now encountered a situation where if something happens in an instance of a class in `Logic.OptionalLogic`, I want to call a static method in a class called `Logic.Editor.EditorWindow` in `Logic.Editor` that it happened. The original library `Logic` is not interested in the event at all.

I was thinking that I would use reflection, but most of the examples I find needs access to the actual library/assembly/namespace and/or class to be able to extract methods from the type. For example

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(System.Type type);
```

requires the type of the assembly, which is not accessible, and

```
System.Type.GetType("Logic.Editor.EditorWindow");
```

returns null, supposedly because `Logic.Editor` is not found, so I cannot call GetMethod on it.

Is it possible to retrieve a static method from a class in an assembly via reflection, that is not accessible to me at all other than known strings, and optionally call it if it is found (if the other assembly is included in the end project)?

I'm restricted to C# 4 and .NET 3.5.

Comment: Seriously wrong approach IMHO. Since there is some dependency from `Logic.OptionalLogic` to `Logic.Editor`, reference the latter from the former directly. And if there is really some reason you want to keep those fully separate, implement some open-ended message hub (even if a very simplistic one) in `Logic`. Then `Logic.OptionalLogic` can notify subscribers and `Logic.Editor` can subscribe to the events - and they both don't need to know anything about each other.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was thinking along those lines, but didn't like the idea of introducing code in the Logic library that doesn't belong there, but I guess you're right - I'm not approaching this the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.80).aspx) in `Logic`, implement it in `Logic.Editor`, and invoke it in `Logic.OptionalLogic`.  If `Logic.OptionalLogic` doesn't have the delegate set, then don't call it.